# Comparing old CPU usage with new one using python not working

Tags: python

I am trying to check the CPU usage and print it the user every 20 seconds.
when the code first runs it sshould print the CPU usage, but after that it should compare the old cpu usage with the new one, and

When there is an increase in CPU usage over 9%, we will print every process using over 1% of the CPU using the code below

```
for process in psutil.process_iter():
      p = process.as_dict()
      if p["memory_percent"] > 1:
        print(p["name"] + " is using " + str(p["memory_percent"]) + " of the CPU")
```

here is what I have tried below

```
import psutil   
import time   

status = 'start'

while(status != 'stop'):
  old_cpu_usage = 0
  cpu_usage_percent = psutil.cpu_percent(1, False) 

  print()

  # if the CPU usage has  not increased by over 10% then it prints the current CPU usage, if not the 
  if(old_cpu_usage==0):
    print(f"The CPU usage is {str(cpu_usage_percent)}%")
    old_cpu_usage = cpu_usage_percent
  elif ((cpu_usage_percent - old_cpu_usage )/cpu_usage_percent * 100 > 9):
    for process in psutil.process_iter():
      p = process.as_dict()
      if p["memory_percent"] > 1:
        print(p["name"] + " is using " + str(p["memory_percent"]) + " of the CPU")
    old_cpu_usage = cpu_usage_percent
  else:
    print(f"The CPU usage did not increase significantly, the usage is {str(cpu_usage_percent)}%")
    old_cpu_usage = cpu_usage_percent
  time.sleep(2)
```

upon trying the solution above, it doesn't work. instead it keeps printing the first `if` statement, and does not make any comparism

Comment: You never change `new_cpu_usage` anywhere.  It's always zero.  I suspect you meant for `new_cpu_usage` and `cpu_usage_percent` to be the same variable.

Comment: @TimRoberts nope, there was a mistake witht the code i just coorrected it, the problem still remains the same

Comment: You are resetting `old_cpu_usage` to 0 in every loop.  No wonder it takes the 0 branch each time.  Move the initialization out of the loop.